# vue-router Failed to resolve async component default: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am getting this unusual error on adding `/otp-validation` route on my Vue Typescript application.

`vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:16 [vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

Route.ts

```
{
path: '/forget-password',
component: () => import('../app/auth/components/forget-password.component.vue'),
  },

{
    path: '/otp-validation',
    component: () => import('../app/auth/components/otp-validation.component.vue'),
  },
```

So, I changed otp-validation with forget-password file and it is working, and otp-validation and forget-password files are identical.

Please help me.

Comment: Do have you tried without **() =>** syntax?

Comment: Do you mean?
` component: import('../app/auth/components/otp-validation.component.vue'), `

Comment: yes, did not works?